# How to pass a string from one vba form to another

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to pass a string value from one form to the next. My first form is "frmLogin" containing the users ID "strId" and Password "strPassword" (it's just a regular login form). The form I am trying to open and pass the string to is "frmProfile1". From frmProfile1, Profile1 users will assign documents to Profile2 users stored as records in Access. These records will contain the ID of the Profile1 user who assigned the document, so it is very important that the value of strId is passed from frmLogin to frmProfile1.

```
'Project: 
'Form: Login Form (frmLogin)
'Author: Nathan Willett
'Created: 9/10/19
'Current Version: 1.0 - 9/10/19

Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public strProfile, strId, strPassword As String

'On 'Button Ok' click, perform the following
Public Sub btnLogin_Click()

    'If ID Login Box is left blank, display "Please enter Login ID"
    If IsNull(Me.txtId) Then
        MsgBox "Please enter Login ID", vbInformation, "Login Error"
        Me.txtId.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    'If Password Box is left blank, display "Please enter Password"
    ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Then
        MsgBox "Please enter Password", vbInformation, "Login Error"
        Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim rs As Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblUserList", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
    rs.FindFirst "fldId='" & Me.txtId & "'"

    'If txtID value does not equal fldId, prompt the user
    If rs.NoMatch = True Then
        MsgBox "Incorrect Login ID. Please try again.", vbInformation, "Login Error"
        Me.txtId.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'If txtPassword value does not equal fldPassword, prompt the user
    If rs!fldPassword <> Me.txtPassword Then
        MsgBox "Incorrect Password. Please try again.", vbInformation, "Login Error"
        Me.txtId.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Look up the users profile version from tblUserList
    strProfile = DLookup("fldPosId", "tblUserList", "fldId='" & Me.txtId.Value & "'")
    strId = rs!fldId
    strPassword = rs!fldPassword

    'Open the corresponding profile form
    Select Case strProfile
        Case "Profile1"
            DoCmd.OpenForm "frmProfile1"
        Case "Profile2"
            DoCmd.OpenForm "frmProfile2"
        Case "Profile3"
            DoCmd.OpenForm "frmProfile3"
        Case "Profile5"
            DoCmd.OpenForm "frmProfile4"
    End Select
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmLogin"
End Sub
'On 'Button Cancel' click, close the program
Private Sub btnCancel_Click()
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmLogin"
End Sub
```

```
'Project:
'Form: frmProfile1
'Author: Nathan Willett
'Created: 9/21/19
'Current Version: 1.0 9/21/19

Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Text468.Text = frmLogin!strId
End Sub
```

Comment: Passwords don't belong in plain text in a database. Hash+salt the password, store the salted hash. Then hash+salt (same salt value) the input, and compare to the stored value. If they match, password was good. Compare hashes, not plain text passwords.

Comment: im using a password input mask on the field. is that alright?

Comment: I'm talking about what's in the database. If you store passwords in plain text, anyone that can access the database tables can spoof any credentials, i.e. might as well not have any passwords, you *cannot* be 100% sure the logged cred is the person the creds claim. The input mask is great, but addresses the security concern of someone looking over your shoulder while you type the password - it does nothing to make the system actually secure.

Comment: Normal users won't have access to those databases but if that's something I need to do I can probably add that in later. Ill do some research.

Comment: Protip: security is a feature, not an add-on. Your "not normal" users /devs can very easily access anyone's credentials. Depending on what this app is doing and why it needs to be secured, you don't want that to be allowed. This is how every single security breach ever happened: devs thinking they can secure things later.

Comment: Also, assuming you havent haxored your way into disabling shift+click into the file, those users pretty much have the ability to see anything alrready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, to refer to controls on forms you would:

```
 forms!yourFormName.ControlName.Value
```

or refer to controls on subforms you would:

```
forms!yourFormName.yourSubFormName.Form.ControlName.Value
```

To open a form and set a value on it you would:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "yourFormName"
Forms!YourFormName.ControlName.Value = Forms!FormOpeningOtherFormName.Control.Value
```

Does this help at all?

For your scenario you would actually need to do this:

```
Select Case strProfile
    Case "Profile1"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmProfile1"
        Forms!frmProfile1.Text468.Text = strId
    Case "frmProfile2"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmProfile2"
        Forms!frmProfile2.Text468.Text = strId
    Case "Profile3"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmProfile3"
        Forms!frmProfile3.Text468.Text = strId
    Case "Profile4"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmProfile4"
        Forms!frmProfile4.Text468.Text = strId
End Select
```

Comment: i also tried doing this by passing it as a parameter with openargs but that didnt work either...

Comment: @NathanWillett It seems youre refering your public variable incorrectly

Comment: @NathanWillett see updated answer, this is of course assuming each form has the same textbox with the same name in the properties window in the other tab